# Jasperreports net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException

Tags: jasper-reports

I have such datasource and it works:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/z12:cars")]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

but I unfortunately I can't use namespaces prefixes so I want to get rid of z12 and put ns uri I thought..

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("./*[local-name() = 'cars' and namespace-uri()='http://sag.sa/spec/c/1.0']")]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

But then in Jasper studio I have this issue while previewing:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("./*[local-name() = 'cars' and namespace-uri()='http://sag.sa/spec/c/1.0']")
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.fillReport(ReportController.java:553)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.access$18(ReportController.java:528)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController$1.run(ReportController.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("./*[local-name() = 'cars' and namespace-uri()='http://sag.sa/spec/c/1.0']")
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.handleEvaluationException(JREvaluator.java:294)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:328)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:673)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:641)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1175)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:529)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:357)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillFrame.evaluate(JRFillFrame.java:175)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:548)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2613)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:836)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:275)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:622)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:135)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource cannot be cast to class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource and net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @63c99f7)
```

Comment: `class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource cannot be cast to class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource` - You passed JREmptyDataSource at JSS

Comment: Ah so its inly previewing problem ? Not compilation one..